# Undefined index in my PHP code

Tags: php

I am trying to add address fields into my registration form but whenever I submit the register Im having error with my address line here is what the error message say

> Notice: Undefined index: address in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\profile\register\index.php on line 9

This is the php code:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if(isset($_REQUEST['sub']) && isset($_POST['gender'])){
        $lname = strtoupper(trim(strip_tags($_POST['lname'])));
        $fname = strtoupper(trim(strip_tags($_POST['fname'])));
        $mname = strtoupper(trim(strip_tags($_POST['mname'])));
        $cours = strtoupper(trim(strip_tags($_POST['gender'])));
        $address =strtoupper(trim(strip_tags($_POST['address'])));
        $email = strip_tags($_POST['email']);

        $pass1 = strip_tags($_POST['pass']);

        if(empty($lname) || empty($fname) || empty($mname) || empty($email) || empty($address)
            || empty($pass1) || empty($cours) || $_POST['gender'] == 'none' ){
            $mess = "<font color='red'><i>Field(s) Required!</i></font>";
        }
                else if(!ctype_alpha($lname)||!ctype_alpha($fname)|| !ctype_alpha($mname)){
                        $mess = "<font color='red'><i>Incorrect Name Format!</i></font>";
                }
                else if(!preg_match('/^[a-zA-z0-9_.]*@[a-zA-z0-9.]*$/', $email)){
                        $mess = "<font color='red'><i>Incorrect Email Format!</i></font>";
                }
        else{
            $host = "localhost"; 
            $user = "root"; 
            $pass = ""; 
            $data = "school"; 

            $connect = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass); 
            mysql_select_db($data, $connect); 

            if(mysql_query("INSERT INTO studentinfo(`userid`, `lastname`, `firstname`, `middlename`, `email`, `address`, `password`, `gender`) 
                VALUES (null,'$lname','$fname','$mname','$email',`$address`,'$pass1','$cours') ")){
                $mess = "Account Added to Database!";
            }
            else{
                $mess = "<font color='red'><i>Data Already Exist!</i></font>";
            }
        }
    }

    if(isset($_REQUEST['back'])){
        header( 'Location: ../' );
    }

    if(!empty($_SESSION['logon'])){
        header( 'Location: ../' );
    }   

?>
```

Comment: It means your `$_POST` does not contains `address` key.

Comment: Where do you have element with `name=address` in your HTML?

Comment: chekck the form , maybe you're missing the field name as "address"

Comment: check the name="address" attribute in HTML form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['sub']) && isset($_POST['gender']))
{
    $address = isset($_POST['address']) ? 
        strtoupper(trim(strip_tags($_POST['address']))) : '';
```

Comment: Doesn´t solve the problem, he need to save address into database, address field is missing in HTML.

Comment: address field is not mandatory in many registration form @panther

Comment: irrelevant, in can´t be mandatory, empty input is sent too (and in this way, the empty field goes through `isset` condition too)

Comment: @panther, I don't think so, OP may have enough knowledge to at least add item in html, anyway I dont have enough time here to

Comment: ashique you are correct it solves the problem, but can you help me again? when I submit the fields it says that my data is already exist. btw i will now choose this as answer

Comment: Thing is that the insert is not working, may be ur query is wrong,

Comment: $sql = "INSERT ....."; like this assign to a variable mysql_query($sql); You just print and see what is wrong in mysql query from phpmyadmin query execute

Comment: alright @user3443026, enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

Before that row check if `$_POST['address']` is defined:

```
if(isset($_POST['address'])){

}
```

Comment: index `address` is undefined not gender!

Comment: Do the same for each POST variable.

Comment: @Veve: not necessary, if one filed is submitted, the second one has to be submitted as well (excluding checkboes, of course).

Comment: Can result in another error telling you that the array key does not exists.

Comment: Really, 4 downvotes because of a simple mistake? Give him a chance to fix it...

Comment: @panther : we don't know what he/she has in his/her html, or what modifications could have been done client side. I tend to never trust what the client send, and test every variables comming from them.

Comment: @Veve" sure, we can test that, no problem, but in this topic problem is elsewhere.

Comment: @panther you're right ;)

Comment: @FIA2008 `isset` check if the given array key exists in this case, so no error will be printed.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably missing an input field named "address".
You can check using PHP:

```
<?php
// long way around
if(array_key_exists("address",$_POST){
  // do something
}
else{
  // not found
}

// short way
$address = array_key_exists("address",$_POST) ? $_POST["address"] : "";
?>
```

Ofcourse, you can do this for all fields and add your own code.
Otherwise, please show us your form layout. You should have

```
<input type="text" name="address" />
```

in your code.

Comment: Better is to update HTMl form, he probably need to get address from user when he save that into databse :-)

Comment: Absolutely true, but I do think it's nice to check if the key exists anyway, just to be sure that your script doesn't generate an error if one field is missing.